# Icicles error: Cannot decrease the defualt face height more than it already

Tags: icicles

On `icy-mode` is enabled, I keep getting following error while I am typing, which makes it very difficult to type:

```
Cannot decrease the defualt face height more than it already.
```

Example case:

`M-x` => `ibuf [TAB]` and when enter a character it gives the warning message.

**[Q]** Can I supress/fix this error?

Based on the windows lise sometime mini buffer also open vertically or horizontally.

My Setup:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/icicles")
(require 'icicles)
(icy-mode 1)

(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 100)
(variable-pitch-mode t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

I added following line into .emacs file.
`(setq icicle-Completions-text-scale-decrease 0.00)`

This was set to `0.75` on the `icicles-opt.el` file.

From the original file `L2451`:

> ````
> icicle-Completions-text-scale-decrease 0.75
>     "*Initial height decrease for text in buffer `*Completions*'. A value of 0.0 means the height is not decreased at all. This is used as
> the argument to function `text-scale-decrease'. ```
> ````